# Set an hidden input value in a forms table

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsp, servlets

I have a table made like that:

```
<%
        EventoModel model = new EventoModel();
        Collection<EventoBean> eventi = new ArrayList<EventoBean>();

        eventi = model.doRetrieveAll();

        if(eventi != null & eventi.size() > 0) {
            Iterator<?> it = eventi.iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                EventoBean bean = (EventoBean)it.next();
                %>
            <form method="get" action="./CartServlet" name="action">
            <table id="customers">
            <tbody>
                <tr>

                    <td><%= bean.getEvento()  %></td>


                    <td><%= bean.getPalinsesto() %></td>
                    <td><%= bean.getCampionato() %></td>
                    <td><%= bean.getData()%></td>
                    <td><%= bean.getSquadraCasa() %></td>
                    <td><%= bean.getSquadraTrasferta() %></td>
                    <% String quota1 = bean.getQuota1(); %>
                    <td>
                        <input type="hidden" value="1" name="action">
                        <input type="hidden" value=<%= bean.getPalinsesto() %> name="palinsesto">
                        <input type="hidden" value=<%= bean.getEvento() %> name="evento">
                        <input type="hidden" name="quota" id="hiddenQuota" value="">

                        <input type="submit" value=<%= quota1 %> onclick="setQuota(<%= quota1 %>);"></td>
                    <% String quotaX = bean.getQuotaX(); %>
                    <td><input type="submit" value=<%= quotaX %> onclick="setQuota(<%= quotaX %>);"></td>
                    <% String quota2 = bean.getQuota2(); %>
                    <td><input type="submit" value=<%= quota2 %> onclick="setQuota(<%= quota2 %>');"></td>

                </tr>
            </tbody>
            </table>
            </form>
            <% 
            }
        }
        %>
```

Now I want to pass the value of the submit button to the hidden input value, I made this javascript function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function setQuota(quota) {
        document.forms["action"].elements["quota"].value = quota;


    }
</script>
```

But it works only with the first row of the table.
How can I fix it? Is the problem in the while loop or where else?

Comment: Give a dynamic id to your controls using customer id if exists and store the id as an attribute in submit button then access that id from click event.

Answer (score 1):

```
function setQuota(quota) {
var myFormElements = document.forms["action"].elements
for (i = 0; i < myFormElements.length; i++) {
  if (myFormElements[i].nodeName === "INPUT" && myFormElements[i].name === "quota") {
    myFormElements[i].value = quota;
  }
}
```

Comment: it doesn't wokr, should I chage that? myFormElements[i].nodeName === "INPUT"

Comment: I corrected my answer as I thought you need to change all hidden elements, now you should change all inputs that have name === "quota". You can delete this part "myFormElements[i].nodeName === "INPUT" it is just to check you are changing input.

Comment: What I have to change in the inputs?

Comment: now it works just with the first row, and the third submit of the row shows me the value of the second

Answer (score 1):

**Add an dummy_css_class to your input element;**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function setQuota(quota) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("dummy_css_class ").value = $YourValue
}
```

Comment: I need to set the value of the hidden input "quota", with this method it only sets the values for the first row, not the others